# Contour integral with square roots in numerator and denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

trying to workout the following integral:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} , \quad  1<a<b$$

where $\gamma$ represents dumbbell contour between $a$ and $b$. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you specify the contour more explicitly?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the location of branch cuts ?

Comment: That too. But what is the dumbbell contour?

Comment: @T.Bongers , I think he means two circles around $a$ and $b$, connected with two lines , like a dubmbbell .

Comment: it is a complete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind (after I googled what a dubbell contour is).

Comment: The branch cut is between $a$ and $b$. The dumbbell contour is also called dogbone contour; a closed contour with small circles around $a$ and $b$ and  are connected by lines located below and above the real axis.

Comment: user91411 , Well we can choose the branch cuts freely but what are the radius of the circles ?

Comment: The radius is infinitesimally small.

Comment: How would you choose the branch cut between a and b ! I suggest you choose a suitable branch cut so that the function is analytic in and on the contour .